# Function to get a Sub String after a selected character in place selectively and dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server

In one of the database tables, I have a `nvarchar` type field that contains a series of special strings combined with some special characters. For example:

```
'HGHGSD_JHJSD_HGSDHGJD_GFSDGFSHDGF_GFSD'
```

or

```
'SJDGh-SUDYSUI-jhsdhsj-YTsagh-ytetyyuwte-sagd'
```

or

```
'hwerweyri~sdjhfkjhsdkjfhds~jsdfhjsdhf~mdnfsd,mfn'
```

Based on a formula, a sub string is always returned after the special character. But this string may be after the first, second or third place of the special character `-` or `_` or `~`. I used `Charindex` and `Substring` function in SQL server. But always only the first part of the character string after the selected character is returned. for example:

```
select SUBSTRING ('hwerweyri~sdjhfkjhsdkjfhds~jsdfhjsdhf~mdnfsd,mfn', 0, CHARINDEX('~', 'hwerweyri~sdjhfkjhsdkjfhds~jsdfhjsdhf~mdnfsd,mfn', 0))
```

returned value:  `hwerweyri`
If there is a solution for this purpose or you have a piece of code that can work in solving this problem, please advise.
It is important to mention that the location of the special character must be entered by ourselves in the function, for example, after the third repetition or the second repetition or the tenth repetition. The method or code should be such that the location can be entered dynamically and the function does not need to be defined statically.
For Example:

```
'HGHGSD_JHJSD_HGSDHGJD_GFSDGFSHDGF_GFSD' ==> 3rd substring ==> 'GFSDGFSHDGF'
'HGHGSD_JHJSD_HGSDHGJD_GFSDGFSHDGF_GFSD' ==> second substring ==> 'HGSDHGJD'
'HGHGSD_JHJSD_HGSDHGJD_GFSDGFSHDGF_GFSD' ==> 1st substring ==> 'JHJSD'
```

And The formula will be sent to the function through a programmed form and the generated numbers will be numbers between 1 and 15. These numbers are actually the production efficiency of a product whose form is designed in C# programming language. These numbers sent to the function are variable and each time these numbers may be sent to the function and applied to the desired character string. The output should look something like the one above. I don't know if I managed to get my point across or if I managed to make my request correctly or not.

Comment: "But this string may be after the first, second or third place of the special character" - how do you identify which one is the correct substring? Please add the desired substring to each of the examples shown.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I mentioned @dale-k `Based on a formula, a sub string is always returned after the special character.`

Comment: Yeah but you haven't explained your formula, so how can we help you develop a solution?

Comment: I added more explanation @dale-k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitWithCte]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1),
    @PlaceOfDelimiter int
)
RETURNS Table
AS 
RETURN
(
WITH SplitedStrings(Ends,Endsp)
    AS (
        SELECT 0 AS Ends, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS Endsp
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Endsp+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,Endsp+1)
            FROM SplitedStrings
            WHERE Endsp > 0
    )
    SELECT f.DataStr
    FROM (
        SELECT 'RowId' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'DataStr' = SUBSTRING(@String,Ends,COALESCE(NULLIF(Endsp,0),LEN(@String)+1)-Ends)
        FROM SplitedStrings
    ) f WHERE f.RowId = @PlaceOfDelimiter + 1
)
```

How to use:

```
select * from [dbo].[SplitWithCte](N'HGHGSD_JHJSD_HGSDHGJD_GFSDGFSHDGF_GFSD', N'_', 3)
```

or

```
select DataStr from [dbo].[SplitWithCte](N'HGHGSD_JHJSD_HGSDHGJD_GFSDGFSHDGF_GFSD', N'_', 3)
```

Result:  `GFSDGFSHDGF`

Comment: `(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))` Warning - logical nonsense. You should point that out and explain that important assumption in your code. It only appears to work correctly - eventually it will not.

Comment: Hi @SMor I can not get your point. For your peace of mind that this code works correctly, I ran it in the online compiler. You can see the result of correct execution of the code in this [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=83897b9a7f385e24a4df12186bed6d3a)